# How to configure apache to execute cgi

Tags: apache, cgi, lamp

I'm very new to LAMP and I've tested if php is running on apache server creating a file testing.php and instead of showing php version and stuff it just show exactly the same thing I typed:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

I tried to use python script and also just show the exactly what I typed:

#!usr/bin/python

```
print ("Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n")
print ("<html>")
print ("<head>)"
print ("<title>Hello world!</title>")
print ("</head>")
print ("<body>")
print ("<h2>Hello world!</h2>")
print ("</body>")
print ("</html>")
```

How should I configure apache to execute cgi?

Answer (score 0):

Have you used a2enmod to enable PHP?

You'll need to do something like:

`sudo a2enmod php7.4`

`sudo systemctl restart apache2`

Comment: Yes, it says that module doens't exists. Should I have to download them???

Comment: You can see if the module is already installed using `ls /etc/apache2/mods-available | grep 'php'`, but yes... if you haven't installed PHP yet you will need to download the packages. `sudo apt update` `sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php` and then restart Apache.

Comment: Linode has a nice guide on the LAMP Stack. It sounds you've already got Apache working but look at the relevant PHP (and mysql) bits. [https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/how-to-install-a-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-20-04/](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/how-to-install-a-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-20-04/) Edit: Note the left sidebar with other guides... there might be one more specific to your system.

Comment: You will need to do a bit of additional config to get python working with Apache. [https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/configuring-apache2-run-python-scripts/](https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/configuring-apache2-run-python-scripts/)

Comment: Yes php worked! And thanks for the guides, I will check them.

Comment: Yay! Glad it's working. I am not as familiar with the python bit... if you need extra help to get those scripts to run, stackoverflow has several topics about it too. I see a few in the Related section on this post. Cheers! :)